# Dependency attribute in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code

```
private MyClass _someProperty

[Dependency]
public MyClass SomeProperty
{
   get{
        if(_someProperty == null)
              _someProperty = new MyClass()
        return (MyClass)_someProperty
      }
}
```

This works good, but I'm directed like "No need to add "get" property for [Dependency]"

I'm not clear with this [Dependency] attribute. When I looked into other code, it is written as

```
[Dependency]
public AnotherClass MyNewClass
{
    get; set;
}
```

When I tried the above for MyClass, it didn't work. It threw the Property is NULL

Can anybody tell me what is the use of the [Dependency] and whether there is an alternate way for MyClass code and why it is coming as "NULL" for that?

Comment: This is in reference to Microsoft Unity, no?

Comment: [Dependency] tells Unity that _if a class containing that attribute on a property is resolved from Unity_, the dependency should also be resolved/injected. If you create a class using `new`, it will have no effect.

Comment: @Joachim - In my case, I have the [Dependency] attribute, but the property is NULL. But I'm able to get the instance of that property in another cs file. For eg. in BO I get the property instantiated, but not in DAO. What could be the possibility?

Comment: @user2138836 In BO, you get the object containing the property from Unity, while in DAO you don't?

Comment: Yes, I don't get in DAO

Comment: @Joachim - The "type and mapTo" config setting for the DAO is available in the web.config, but still the instance is not created.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the `DependencyAttribute`. The latter case is simply a auto-generated property. If you like to use this syntax you have to fill in the value within your constructor.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        SomeProperty = new AnotherClass();
    }

    public AnotherClass SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Be aware that you in this case you can't perform any checks within the getter or setter. So if you need any nullity checks or like to raise an event within the setter, you have to implement the getter and setter on yourself.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private AnotherClass _SomeProperty;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _SomeProperty = new AnotherClass();
    }

    public AnotherClass SomeProperty
    {
        get { return _SomeProperty; }
        set
        {
            if(value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("SomeProperty");

            if(value != _SomeProperty)
            {
                _SomeProperty = value;
                // ToDo: Implement RaiseEvent() and declare event.
                RaiseEvent(MyEvent);
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But can I know the use of [Dependency] in general? May be brief it?

Comment: @user2138836: Sorry, but i never used the Dependency attribute. So i can't tell you anything about it.